# Stackoverflow Exception with many-to-many relationship object in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, stack-overflow

I'm using entity framework in .net core, Note that my knowledge of entity framework is somewhat limited, so take my assumptions with a pinch of salt.

Teams & Users are the two objects that I have trouble with.

They have a joining table, `UserTeam` because `Users` can have many `Teams`, and `Teams` can have many `Users`.

I figured out how to have them saved in a sqlite database using entityframework, and it's all fine. It took me a while to realize I had to use `Include` to get the joining property, but now it works in that part.

At some point, I have to expose that object on the API, so I have matching `UserDTO` & `TeamDTO`. There is my issue. `UserDTO`s have a list of `TeamDTO`s, and `TeamDTO`s have a list of `UserDTO`s, because that's how they should look like. Right?

But when I am mapping them, I get into a `StackOverflowException`, which is normal, because I'm looping on the list of teams, which contains `Users`, and for each of those `Users`, I end up recreating `Teams`, and so on.

Right now, I just added a boolean check in the loop, so when I call `.ToDTO()` I can decide to skip the users/teams from inner levels, but that does not look like a proper fix to me. Is it?

What do you guys suggest ?

Here is what I'm doing exactly :

```
public static TeamDTO ToDTO(this Team team, EatupContext context, bool doOnce = false)
{
    var dto = new TeamDTO
    {
        Id = team.Id,
        Name = team.Name,
    };

    var users = new List<UserDTO>();
    foreach (var userTeam in team.UsersTeams)
    {
        var user = context.Users.Find(userTeam.UserId);

        if (doOnce)
            user.TeamsUsers = new List<UserTeam>();

        users.Add(user.ToDTO(context, true));
    }

    dto.Users = users;

    return dto;
}
```

```
public static UserDTO ToDTO(this User user, EatupContext context, bool doOnce = false)
{
    var dto = new UserDTO
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        NickName = user.NickName,
        Email = user.Email,
        Image = user.Image,

    };

    var teams = new List<TeamDTO>();
    foreach (var userTeam in user.TeamsUsers)
    {
        var team = context.Teams.Find(userTeam.TeamId);
        if (doOnce)
            team.UsersTeams = new List<UserTeam>();
        teams.Add(team.ToDTO(context, true));
    }

    dto.Teams = teams;

    return dto;
}
```

Because I have a strong feeling my issue might come from there, I'm gonna share this piece of information :

When I'm looping through the entity objects `UserTeams`(of either a team or a user), the `Team` object is `null`, so I have to fetch the `Team` from the context using its ID, and then I have everything I need. It's very strange because everything appears to be working fine and the database is complete and healthy. Its just the `UserTeam` object that is missing the `Team` property.

But my assumption is that between fetching a new `Team` from the ID, and getting the `Team` from the `UserTeam`, both would create the same result I have now when I call `ToDTO()`: I still would need to loop through its users and have that overflow exception.

This seems like a very common issue that should have been dealt with by a lot of people, but I can't really find my answer using the keywords of my title.

What's my next step ?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the stackoverflow due to the fact that you're circularly calling the 2 methods.

In the Team Version of the `ToDTO` method, you call the user version, which in turn calls the team version and so on.

If your model is not structured something like below you should consider it. There's no need to actually model `UserTeam` as EFs mapping should take care of this. That's considering that you've specified one end of the relationship as the primary.

```
public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
    //properties we don't care about

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Teams = new List<User>();
    }

    //properties we don't care about

    public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The only differences between your class definition and mine is that the collection is virtual, and that I'm using a List and not an ICollection. Is that supposed to make a difference for EF?

Comment: I always put that for lazy loading purposes, but it's not essential. The main point is that one method is calling the other in a circular fashion and causing your stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah I know and understand very well the reason why i'm getting a stackoverflow, I just dont know what I can do differently except add a boolean to avoid it. I need to expose the users / teams

Comment: Move the logic for retrieving the entites out of the `ToDTO` methods. It doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 0):

just turn off lazy loading and use include method when you need to fetch lists of objects.

this is for DbContext class

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

and this is for the controllers

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    // Load all blogs, all related posts, and all related comments.
    var blogs1 = context.Blogs
                        .Include(b => b.Posts.Select(p => p.Comments))
                        .ToList();

    // Load all users, their related profiles, and related avatar.
    var users1 = context.Users
                        .Include(u => u.Profile.Avatar)
                        .ToList();

    // Load all blogs, all related posts, and all related comments  
    // using a string to specify the relationships.
    var blogs2 = context.Blogs
                        .Include("Posts.Comments")
                        .ToList();

    // Load all users, their related profiles, and related avatar  
    // using a string to specify the relationships.
    var users2 = context.Users
                        .Include("Profile.Avatar")
                        .ToList();
}
```

source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data